# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API route parameter to all controllers and pass a service class to all controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

I need to initialize a service with a route parameter, and pass this service class to all the controllers, for instance:

- route `/{business}/customers`
- initialize the `MyService` class with the business parameter
- pass `MyService` to all controllers.

How do I achieve this?

I try to create an abstract controller with the class service:

```
[Route("api/{business}")]
[ApiController]
public abstract class CBaseController : ControllerBase
{
    public MyService _mySerice;

    public CBaseController(int business) 
    {
        _mySerice = new SdkConnect(business);
    }
}
```

This did not work

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution by adding `IHttpContextAccessor` to services in Program.cs and creating an abstract controller that injects `IHttpContextAccessor` on the constructor

```
 [Route("api/{business}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public abstract class CBaseController : ControllerBase
    {
        protected readonly MyService sdk;
        public CBaseController(IHttpContextAccessor context) 
        {
            int? business;
            var routeValues = context.HttpContext?.Request.RouteValues;

            if (routeValues == null)
                throw new BadHttpRequestException();

            business = Convert.ToInt32(routeValues["business"]);

            if(business == null)
                throw new BadHttpRequestException("business not present");

            sdk = new MyService(business);
        }
    }
```

Then I extends from this controller

```
    [ApiController]
    public class MyController : CBaseController 
    {
        public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
           sdk.Do();
        }
    }
```